# Readium and Sony URMS Integration on iOS app

Tags: swift, sdk

I've currently started new project which is related to E-Books. This is my first project on such type. I need to integrate URMS SDK and Readium SDK and also synchronize these two stuffs. I found Readium SDK on github and integrate the suggested frameworks on my app (R2Shared.framework, R2Streamer.framework, R2Navigator.framework, ObjectMapper.framework, GCDWebServers and so on). But I haven't found any clue to use them in my project. Also I have to synchronize URMS SDK with Readium.

**Is there anyone who can share something about Readium SDK and how can I use them on my project?**

**Thanks**

Comment: Did you have some results on this integration? did you take exemple on the test application provided with the modules? What about Sony URMS?

Comment: I found Radium SDK an expensive to buy and also don't have any documentations on that. Thus decided to use Active Text Book.

Comment: For the record, the Readium SDK is FREE for a year now. ActiveTextBook, from Evident Point, is based on the Readium SDK and can definitely be a good choice for those wanting a ready to use app or high level SDK. Sony URMS is not on the market anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, Sony URMS is no longer on the market from March 2019.